# How to parse JSON's array of numbers

Tags: json, jaxb

I'm facing the following situation parsing a JSON. 
The JSON I want to unmarshal contains an array of numbers (doubles) like this:

```
"position":[52.50325,13.39062]
```

So there is no name/value pairs.

The Problem is that I can't get the value of this array. In the Java object modeling the JSON I defined the position attribute as list of Doubles: `List<Double>` but after the unmarshel, the position attribute is always null.

For testing purpose I changed the content of the JSON like that:

```
position: [„52.50325“ ,“ 13.39062“ ]
```

and then there is no issue, I get the list with two elements.  (Btw, this happens regardless if the position is defined as list of Strings or list of Doubles (`List<String>` or `List<Double>`))

So a workaround could be to alter the JSON response and mark this numbers as string before unmarshaling it, but I would like to avoid that, and  I’m wondering if there is solution to get the value of a number array?

Here is a snapshot from the code:

`ResultsListDO.java`:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Double> position;

public List<Double> getPosition()
{
  if (position == null) {
    position = new ArrayList<Double>();
  }

  return this.position;
}
```

JSON unmarshal:

```
context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().build(), ResultsListDO.class);
JSONUnmarshaller um = context.createJSONUnmarshaller();
ResultsListDO resultsList = um.unmarshalFromJSON(source.getReader(), ResultsListDO.class);
```

Comment: It's weird that you have logic in your getter/setter in a data object.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955319/getters-and-setters-performing-additional-logic

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)) lead and a member of the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Unless you have annotated your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` the problem is probably that your annotation is on the field rather than the `get` method (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Foo {

    protected List<Double> position;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public List<Double> getPosition()
    {
      if (position == null) {
        position = new ArrayList<Double>();
      }

      return this.position;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

Below I'll demonstrate that everything works using MOXy as the JSON-binding provider.

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum18355753/input.json");
        Foo foo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Foo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
   "position" : [ 52.50325, 13.39062 ]
}
```